# Joining a dataframe against a filtered version of itself

Tags: join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, anti-join

I have two dataframes, `left` and `right`. The latter, `right`, is a subset of `left`, such that `left` contains all the rows `right` does. I want to use `right` to remove redundant rows from `left` by doing a simple "left_anti" join.

I've discovered that the join doesn't work if I use a filtered version of `left` on the right. It works only if I reconstruct the right dataframe from scratch.

- What is going on here?
- Is there a workaround that doesn't involve recreating the right dataframe?

```py
from pyspark.sql import Row, SparkSession

import pyspark.sql.types as t

schema = t.StructType(
    [
        t.StructField("street_number", t.IntegerType()),
        t.StructField("street_name", t.StringType()),
        t.StructField("lower_street_number", t.IntegerType()),
        t.StructField("upper_street_number", t.IntegerType()),
    ]
)
data =  [
    # Row that conflicts w/ range row, and should be removed
    Row(
        street_number=123,
        street_name="Main St",
        lower_street_number=None,
        upper_street_number=None,
    ),
    # Range row
    Row(
        street_number=None,
        street_name="Main St",
        lower_street_number=120,
        upper_street_number=130,
    ),
]


def join_files(left_side, right_side):
    join_condition = [
      (
        (right_side.lower_street_number.isNotNull())
        & (right_side.upper_street_number.isNotNull())
        & (right_side.lower_street_number <= left_side.street_number)
        & (right_side.upper_street_number >= left_side.street_number)
      )
    ]
    return left_side.join(right_side, join_condition, "left_anti")


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
left = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

right_fail = left.filter("lower_street_number IS NOT NULL")
result = join_files(left, right_fail)
result.count() # Returns 2 - both rows still present


right_success = spark.createDataFrame([data[1]], schema)
result = join_files(left, right_success)
result.count() # Returns 1 - the "left_anti" join worked as expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alias the DF's:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


def join_files(left_side, right_side):
    join_condition = [
      (
        (F.col("right_side.lower_street_number").isNotNull())
        & (F.col("right_side.upper_street_number").isNotNull())
        & (F.col("right_side.lower_street_number") <= F.col("left_side.street_number"))
        & (F.col("right_side.upper_street_number") >= F.col("left_side.street_number"))
      )
    ]
    return left_side.join(right_side, join_condition, "left_anti")


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
left = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema).alias("left_side")


right_fail = left.filter("lower_street_number IS NOT NULL").alias("right_side")
result = join_files(left, right_fail)
print(result.count()) # Returns 2 - both rows still present


right_success = spark.createDataFrame([data[1]], schema).alias("right_side")
result = join_files(left, right_success)
result.count() # Returns 1 - the "left_anti" join worked as expected
```

Don't know which pyspark version you are on but `pyspark==3.0.1`, I get the following explanatory error.

```
AnalysisException: Column lower_street_number#522, upper_street_number#523, lower_street_number#522, upper_street_number#523 are ambiguous. It's probably because you joined several Datasets together, and some of these Datasets are the same. This column points to one of the Datasets but Spark is unable to figure out which one. Please alias the Datasets with different names via `Dataset.as` before joining them, and specify the column using qualified name, e.g. `df.as("a").join(df.as("b"), $"a.id" > $"b.id")`. You can also set spark.sql.analyzer.failAmbiguousSelfJoin to false to disable this check.;
```

Comment: I'm on 2.4.3. This works nicely, though I'm confused as to why it would think these datasets are the same, since we're referencing them by their explicit variable

Comment: Spark holds the references to the columns, when you assign it to a new variable these references are not changed. When self-joining it has has 2 identical references to pick from (2 dataframes) and that results in the error.